# return number of days between two date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I've seen a very few questions like this one but none have a solution that quite works with with the structure I have.

My current query creates a table with 4 columns, 2 of which are dates.

I declare this as a table `@tblTransactions` which I later call in a select statement. 
I need the final select statement to have a 5th column which shows the number of days between the two dates.

```
SELECT *
       ,(t.PremDueDate - t.LastTdate) AS 'tpFactor'          <-------- This doesn't work
FROM
       @tblTransactions t
```

the above code obviously doesn't work since PremDueDate and LastTdate are both of datatype `date`.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to get the number of days between two dates:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, t.PremDueDate, t.LastTdate) AS 'tpFactor'
FROM @tblTransactions t
```

Comment: Worked well. I see that `DATEDIFF(dd, t.PremDueDate, t.LastTdate) AS 'tpFactor'` works as well. What's the difference between `DD` and `DAY`??

Comment: It's the same, both `dd` and `d` are alias/abbreviations for `DAY`. They all work just fine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
    ,DATEDIFF(DD, t.LastTdate, t.PremDueDateP) AS 'tpFactor'
FROM
   @tblTransactions t
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`DATEDIFF(dd, t.PremDueDate, t.LastTdate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)